# Safe patter to add translation json to i18n react after initialisation of i18n object

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

What would be safe and proper way to add translations to i18n object inside react app fetching them from /public folder? Goal is to have hot swappable translation.json file so i dont have to recompile and redeploy whole app whenever I want to update translation.json

Documentation says:

```
resources = translation.json

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: "en", 

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
    }
  });

  export default i18n;
```

and after that:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import './i18n';
import App from './App';

// append app to dom
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

but i want to load translations( resources) when app runs from public folder.

example (pseudo):

```
useEffect(()=> 
fetch('./translations').then(r => i18n.resources(r.data.translation)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an i18next backend plugin: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations#load-using-a-backend-plugin

This blog post explains step by step, how this could look like, i.e. with the usage of [i18next-http-backend](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend): https://locize.com/blog/how-to-internationalize-react-i18next/#separate